# Transact SQL - Get first character every 5 characters of a variable length string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a string that looks like the following

A1234B1234C1234

I would like to take the first character every 5 characters.

The result would be

ABC

The string length is variable so the length could be 5, 10 , 20 , 30 ect

Comment: Where is this value stored? In a table? A variable? What version of SQL Server?

Comment: you need only string value ignore number when you get first five right ?

Comment: I think the fact that the OP wants the letters could be a little misleading, @PiyushKachhadiya . Though, Stanton, it would be helpful to have more examples. Will the string *always* be in the format `A0000A0000~`? If so, then this could be much easier (again, pending SQL Server version).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using a fully supported version of SQL Server, and you *do* actually want to get the every 5th character, you could use a Tally and `STRING_AGG` to achieve this:

```sql
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (8000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4)
SELECT STRING_AGG(SS.C,'') AS NewColumn
FROM (VALUES('A1234B1234C1234'))V(YourColumn)
     JOIN Tally T ON LEN(YourColumn) >= T.I
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(V.YourColumn,T.I,1)))SS(C)
WHERE (T.I-1) % 5 = 0
GROUP BY V.YourColumn;
```

If, however, you actually just want to retain the alpha characters, I would use `TRANSLATE` and `REPLACE`:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(TRANSLATE(V.YourColumn, '0123456789',REPLICATE('|',LEN('0123456789'))),'|','') AS NewColumn
FROM (VALUES('A1234B1234C1234'))V(YourColumn)
```

---

Note, if the value is a variable, I would recommend this method if using the Tally solution:

```sql
DECLARE @YourString varchar(8000) = 'A1234B1234C1234';

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (LEN(@YourString)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4)
SELECT STRING_AGG(SS.C,'') AS NewColumn
FROM Tally T
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@YourString,T.I,1)))SS(C)
WHERE (T.I-1) % 5 = 0;
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I should have mentioned that the 1 character can be variable and not just a letter

Comment: Is there a way to put your last query into a function.

Comment: Yes, you could put it into an **inline** table value function (don't use a multi-line table value function, they perform terribly), @StantonRoux, and then `@YourString` would simply be the parameter for the iTVF instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Create function UDF_ExtractAlphabets
(  
  @input varchar(255)  
)  
Returns varchar(255)  
As  
Begin  
  Declare @alphabetIndex int = Patindex('%[^a-zA-Z]%', @input)  
  Begin  
    While @alphabetIndex > 0  
    Begin  
      Set @input = Stuff(@input, @alphabetIndex, 1, '' )  
      Set @alphabetIndex = Patindex('%[^a-zA-Z]%', @input )  
    End  
  End  
  Return @input
End


SELECT left(dbo.UDF_ExtractAlphabets(yourtext),5)  FROM dbo.tablename
```

[image]

Comment: I really can't recommend this answer. SQL is a set based language, and the above uses a `WHILE`; which are terribly slow. Also this is a multi-line scalar function, which can be notoriously slow themselves. This may work, but it'll be terribly unperformant.

Comment: @Larnu it is SQL-SERVER Code.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't T-SQL, I said it's not performant.

Comment: @Larnu Add Result Also Check please.

Comment: That doesn't change my point about performance, @Piyush. I never said it was incorrect.

Comment: I explain in my [original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70680263/transact-sql-get-first-character-every-5-characters-of-a-variable-length-strin/70680400?noredirect=1#comment124949681_70680400)... This method will be **slow**, and I state why.

Comment: @Larnu i understand that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240992/discussion-between-piyush-kachhadiya-and-larnu).

Comment: I rarely participate in chats, Piyush, though you haven't contributed anything to the chat, so I'm not sure what you've asked to discuss. If you do, put it in the chat, however, please remember that I often don't participate, Thanks.